# Less (css) - Can I re-declare a color variable that is referenced in other color definitions?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

So let's say I have the following color definitions

```
@gray-base:              #000;
@gray-darker:            lighten(@gray-base, 13.5%); // #222
@gray-dark:              lighten(@gray-base, 20%);   // #333
@gray:                   lighten(@gray-base, 33.5%); // #555
@gray-light:             lighten(@gray-base, 46.7%); // #777
@gray-lighter:           lighten(@gray-base, 93.5%); // #eee
```

If, after the above code, I re-declare `@gray-base`, will all the other `@gray` definitions which are based on `@gray-base` change, or do I have to re-declare them all?

The particular use case I am after, is I want to be able to override bootstrap variables from an external variable.less file, to keep the bootstrap repo untouched to make it easier to update.

Comment: Yes, you can. See [Lazy Loading](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-lazy-loading).

Comment: Yes you can change the base variable but all of the child variables will be effected. eg: if you change #000 to something else, gray-darker will no longer be #222 but it will be relative of 13.5% lighter of the new gray-base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that you have at the beginning of the file your code from above and change somewhere afterwards your `@gray-base` color. Will all the other colors change?

Yes.

[Have a look](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbGMra)
Didn't know exactly how to make this stick, but if you comment the later `@gray-base` out, you see the color changing.